# D3 collapsible tree, change colour of knots and avoid line/text overlap

Tags: d3.js

So here I am with this d3 tree:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HwcZecZtLor51cyNSGSL?p=preview

As you may see, the tree is a bit complex and some of the leave names may be quite long. My main questions are:

Can we change the colour of specific knots (some blue, some red)
and is there any way I can make it so that the text of a leave does not overlap with the link with the previous level? This happens especially when the link is a straight line.

My JS skills are lacking to say the least as these are my baby steps into this world and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is easy. The colour of a node is set in line 90 in your example --

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
```

To change the colour, all you need to do is adapt this line. In the function that returns the colour, you have access to the data that you bind to the nodes, so you can use any of the data attributes to decide the colour. Note that only the fill colour is set here and not the outline stroke colour, but you could easily add `.style("stroke", ...)`.

The answer to your second question is much more complex. The functionality you're asking for is not built in to D3, so you would have to do that yourself. Note that this would be quite a complex thing to do because you would have to figure out the positions and bounding boxes of the links and text elements dynamically. Doing this in a general fashion would be a major project.

I suggest that you experiment with the label placements to avoid overlap as much as possible. This will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Lars,

So could you make certain specific in a specific color? Say, you want the node "Private Sector" to be in blue and "Private Sector" to be in yellow..?

Any idea where I could start with label placements? I don't suppose I can adjust the label placements for specific nodes only? 

Muchos gracias again

Comment: You can do all of this for specific nodes, just check the data (e.g. `if(d.name == "Private Sector") { return "blue"; }` etc). A good place to start with the label placements would be to play around with the `text-anchor` property, which will adjust the placement relative to the node.

Comment: Ah, this is giving me a hard time. I edited the HTML between 93 and 140 and tried to provide a different stroke for a number of these nodes but it turns out that only the last line is being registered as all of the other nodes are left out in light blue. I feel I am missing something very basic here :(

Comment: Without some more detail I can't really help you with that.

Comment: Well, I used a lot of strings like
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.name === "Intelligence Officers" ? "red" : ""; })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.name === "Military" ? "red" : ""; });

The point being that I want the nodes for  "Military" and "Intelligence Officers" to have a red stroke, but only "Military" has one (only the last string of this whole list is actually taken into account and has a red stroke around its node instead of all of the strings),

I hope I am making more sense now

Comment: Yes, only the last one of these will take effect. You need to put everything into a single function that you call for `stroke`, i.e. have `if` statements that check every condition.

Comment: Could you please give me one example? That will get me started,
Sorry for my lack of skills, I appreciate you taking your time to explain this.

Comment: `.style("stroke", function(d) { if(d.name == "Intelligence Officers") { return "red"; } else if(d.name == "Military") { return "red"; } else { return ""; } })`